# Stronger than AM-GM (five variables)

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ and $e$ be non-negative numbers. Prove that:
$$\frac{(a+b)(b+c)(c+d)(d+e)(e+a)}{32}\geq\frac{a+b+c+d+e}{5}\sqrt[5]{a^4b^4c^4d^4e^4}$$
I am not sure that it's true.

I have a proof for the following inequality.

Let $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ and $e$ be non-negative numbers. Prove that:
$$\left(\frac{(a+b)(b+c)(c+d)(d+e)(e+a)}{32}\right)^{128}\geq\left(\frac{a+b+c+d+e}{5}\right)^{125}(abcde)^{103}$$
but it's not comforting.

Comment: Is the title appropriate?;-)

Comment: Setting $a=b=c=d=e$ in the second inequality gives $a^{128}\geq a^{640}$, which only holds for $a\leq 1$.  Did you mean to have something different for the exponents on the RHS?  The claim would be false for any exponents though by the same argument.

Comment: @tatan Because by AM-GM $\frac{(a+b)(b+c)(c+d)(d+e)(e+a)}{32}\leq\left(\frac{a+b+c+d+e}{5}\right)^5$

Comment: The scaling is wrong.  The left side is homogeneous of degree $5$, the right side degree $2$.

Comment: @ Peder @Robert Israel Thx!

Comment: Thanks for correcting the statement.  Could you adjust the second inequality too?

Comment: @Peder it's true!

Comment: I must be missing something then because for the second inequality the homogeneous order of the LHS appears to be 128 while the RHS seems to have order $125+103*5$.  Shouldn't the orders add up?  I thought maybe you meant to have the last power be $3/5$?

Comment: @Peder The order of the left side is $128\cdot5$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg My solution is ugly. Do you have nice solutions now?

Comment: @River L No. I have a solution for the inequality with $128$ and $125$.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is true. Let us prove it.

With computer, here is an ugly solution:

WLOG, assume that $e=1$. We need to prove that
\begin{align}
f &= \ln (a+b) + \ln (b+c) + \ln (c+d) + \ln (d+1) + \ln (1+a) - \ln 32\\
&\qquad - \ln(a+b+c+d+1) + \ln 5 - \frac{4}{5}(\ln a + \ln b + \ln c + \ln d)\\
& \ge 0.
\end{align}
It suffices to prove that $f\ge 0$ for $a, b, c, d > 0$ satisfying 
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}=
\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial c}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial d} =0$, that is,
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{a+b} + \frac{1}{1+a} - \frac{1}{a+b+c+d+1} - \frac{4}{5a} &= 0, \qquad (1)\\
\frac{1}{a+b} + \frac{1}{b+c} - \frac{1}{a+b+c+d+1} - \frac{4}{5b} &= 0,\qquad (2) \\
\frac{1}{b+c} + \frac{1}{c+d} - \frac{1}{a+b+c+d+1} - \frac{4}{5c} &= 0, \qquad (3)\\
\frac{1}{c+d} + \frac{1}{1+d} - \frac{1}{a+b+c+d+1} - \frac{4}{5d} &= 0. \qquad (4)
\end{align}
From (1) and (2), we have
\begin{align}
c &= \frac{b(a^2-ab+a+4b)}{4a^2+ab+4a-4b},
\end{align}
$$d =  -\frac{4 a^5+15 a^4 b+a^3 b^2+12 a^4-15 a^3 b-7 a^2 b^2+12 a^3-50 a^2 b+8 a b^2+4 a^2-20 a b+16 b^2}{24 a^4+10 a^3 b+a^2 b^2+28 a^3-35 a^2 b-8 a b^2+4 a^2-20 a b+16 b^2}$$
which, when inserted into (3) and (4), results in
$$g(a,b) = 0, \quad h(a,b) = 0$$
where $g(a,b)$ and $h(a,b)$ are two polynomials.

Using resultant, we have
\begin{align}
F(a) &= \mathrm{Resultant}(g, h, b)\\
& = C_1 a^{18} (3 a+4) (9 a^2-18 a-32) (32 a^2+18 a-9) (4 a^2-9 a-8) (4 a^2+33 a+4)^2 (a-1)^3\\
&\quad \cdot (2 a-3)^4 (a-4)^6 (1+a)^{12}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
G(b) &= \mathrm{Resultant}(g, h, a)\\
& = C_2b^{25} (3 b-1) (2 b+3) (9 b^2-18 b-32) (4 b^2+43 b-2) (32 b^2+18 b-9) (32 b^2-228 b-9)\\
&\quad \cdot (9 b^2+228 b-32) (b-6)^3 (b-1)^8
\end{align}
where $C_1, \ C_2$ are constants.

All solutions $(a,b)$ of the system of equations $g(a,b)=0$ and $h(a,b)=0$ satisfy $F(a)=0$ and $G(b)=0$.
$F(a)=0$ has six distinct positive real roots $a_i,\ i=1, 2, \cdots, 6$. $G(b)=0$ has eight distinct positive real roots $b_j, \ j=1, 2, \cdots, 8$.
Checking all $(a_i, b_j), \ i=1, 2, \cdots, 6; \ j=1,2,\cdots, 8$, we find that the system of equations $g(a,b)=0$ and $h(a,b)=0$
has only one positive real root $a=1, \ b=1$ such that $a, b, c, d >0$. We are done.

Comment: What do you think? Is it true or wrong? I mean the starting inequality.